# Как отобразить отступы текста innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, строки

У меня в переменной есть текст, я вставляю его в innerHTML. Но перенос текста (ентер) и несколько пробелов оно не видит. Как преобразовать пробелы я знаю, но как ентер преобразовать в `\n` или в `<br>`?

На скрине видно редакт текста блока через F12, как-бы отступы есть, но оно думает, что это не отступ. (Если что, в console.log выводит такой же адекватный текст, с переносами строк.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат - текст без переноса строк.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А может проще стилями добавить поддержку переносов и пробелов в нужный блок? Свойство `white-space`.

Comment: Точно, я ставил white-space normal и думал, что это не то, но нужно было ставить white-space:pre. Столько времени потратил, а нужна одна строчка. ужс. Напишите ответ, рейтинг приятен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может проще стилями добавить поддержку переносов и пробелов в нужный блок? Стиль `white-space:pre` или даже `white-space:pre-wrap` (как `pre`, только с переносом на новую строку, если не помещается).